# How to build/install Travis Build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, travis-ci

I'd like to use [Travis Build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build), but there are no build/install instructions other than the very vague `ln -s PATH_TO_TRAVIS_BUILD ~/.travis/travis-build` to use it with Travis CLI. I assume it's some sort of incantation along the lines of `gem install bundler && bundle install --path vendor/bundle && bundle exec something`, but that `something` eludes me.

Comment: You can use it [as an add-on for the CLI interface](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build#use-as-addon-for-cli) a.k.a. `Travis.rb` by `git clone`ing the repo into `~/.travis/travis-build` (CD = `~/.travis` when cloning)

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь That doesn't work. I did effectively `cd ~/.travis && git clone git@github.com:travis-ci/travis-build.git && cd ~/dev/root && travis build`, but it still says "unknown command build".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the [Use as addon for CLI section in the README](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build#use-as-addon-for-cli), the following worked for me:

- `git clone`ing the repo into *some* persistent directory (`~/GitHub` for me)
- from `~/GitHub/travis-build` I used `ln -s $(pwd) ~/.travis/travis-build` (taken almost verbatim from the README)
- after running `travis` (no arguments) I got the following output:

  ```
  nabijaczleweli@klusikomp-vm:~/.travis$ travis
  Usage: travis COMMAND ...

  Available commands:

          accounts       displays accounts and their subscription status
          branches       displays the most recent build for each branch
          cache          lists or deletes repository caches
          cancel         cancels a job or build
          compile        compiles a build script from .travis.yml
          console        interactive shell
          disable        disables a project
          enable         enables a project
          encrypt        encrypts values for the .travis.yml
          encrypt-file   encrypts a file and adds decryption steps to .travis.yml
          endpoint       displays or changes the API endpoint
          env            show or modify build environment variables
          help           helps you out when in dire need of information
          history        displays a projects build history
          init           generates a .travis.yml and enables the project
          lint           display warnings for a .travis.yml
          login          authenticates against the API and stores the token
          logout         deletes the stored API token
          logs           streams test logs
          monitor        live monitor for what's going on
          open           opens a build or job in the browser
          pubkey         prints out a repository's public key
          raw            makes an (authenticated) API call and prints out the result
          report         generates a report useful for filing issues
          repos          lists repositories the user has certain permissions on
          requests       lists recent requests
          restart        restarts a build or job
          settings       access repository settings
          setup          sets up an addon or deploy target
          show           displays a build or job
          sshkey         checks, updates or deletes an SSH key
          status         checks status of the latest build
          sync           triggers a new sync with GitHub
          token          outputs the secret API token
          version        outputs the client version
          whatsup        lists most recent builds
          whoami         outputs the current user

  run `/usr/local/bin/travis help COMMAND` for more infos
  ```

Note line 10 thereof: `compile        compiles a build script from .travis.yml`, indicating that it does, indeed, work.

Comment: I screwed up, because I naively thought the command would be `build`, not `compile`. I just had to do as you said plus install the `travis-build` bundle.